# Hash rate for litecoind is way below the one I get for bitcoind, is this normal?

Tags: bitcoind, litecoin, mining-theory, hashpower, algorithms

I'm running bitcoind on an Ubuntu EC2 image in the Amazon cloud; on another identical image I'm running litecoind. I compiled both of these on the bitcoind instance. According to the getmininginfo command, my hashes per second for litecoind ranges around 300, while for bitcoind it is over 300000; 3 orders of magnitude greater. Is this normal, or have I botched something?

Comment: You might want to edit the title - it makes it sound like you're not getting any hashes in litecoin.

Comment: how to check if litecoind daemon is actually hashing? Is this the 'networkkhashps' figure in getmininginfo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mining in Litecoin uses a significantly different algorithmic pattern which takes substantially longer to complete a "round".

Litecoin uses scrypt while Bitcoin uses SHA256. Usually devices are measured in Khash/Mhash for Litecoin and Mhash/Ghash for Bitcoin.

The initial concept behind this is that it would be GPU proof so everyone could use their PC. GPUs can still perform substantially well.

Comment: thanks! I suppose I could have found that out with more Googling but my first tries were fruitless.